# When I am trying to remove widget getting this error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

When I try to remove the ball widget getting the below error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'

I have tried to use clear_widget as well as remove_widget. How can I tackle this problem?

How can I use unschedule clock function to pause the game?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/Hochshule_HOF/Semester_2/Concepts/PingPong/main.py", line 104, in <module>
     PongApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Sangram\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Sangram\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Sangram\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Sangram\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Sangram\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "C:\Users\Sangram\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 591, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "D:/Hochshule_HOF/Semester_2/Concepts/PingPong/main.py", line 72, in update
     self.clear_widgets()
   File "C:\Users\Sangram\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 696, in clear_widgets
     remove_widget(child)
   File "C:\Users\Sangram\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 678, in remove_widget
     widget.parent = None
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1096, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Sangram\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 143, in update_intermediates
     fn(args, None, None)
   File "C:\Users\Sangram\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 73, in call_fn
     e_value = eval(value, idmap)
   File "D:\Hochshule_HOF\Semester_2\Concepts\PingPong\pong.kv", line 52, in <module>
     center: self.parent.center
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'
```

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.text import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
)
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock


class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


class PongBall(Widget):
    # velocity of the ball on x and y axis
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)

    # referencelist property so we can use ball.velocity as
    # a shorthand, just like e.g. w.pos for w.x and w.y
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    # ``move`` function will move the ball one step. This
    #  will be called in equal intervals to animate the ball
    # Latest Position = Current velocity + Current Position
    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(8, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    # moving the ball by calling the move()
    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        # bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        # bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        # went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

        if self.player1.score == 2:
            self.ids.winner.text = 'Player 1 WINS'
            self.clear_widgets()
#            self.remove_widget(self.ids.score1)
#            self.remove_widget(self.ids.score2)
#            self.remove_widget(self.ids.player_left)
#            self.remove_widget(self.ids.player_right)

        if self.player2.score == 2:
            self.ids.winner.text = 'Player 2 WINS'
            self.remove_widget(self.ids.score1)
            self.remove_widget(self.ids.score2)
            self.remove_widget(self.ids.player_left)
            self.remove_widget(self.ids.player_right)
            self.remove_widget(self.ids.pong_ball)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y


class PongApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'icon.png'
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 100.0)
        #        game.game_over()
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

pong.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            source: 'ball.png'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PongPaddle>:
    size: 50, 350
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'rect.jpg'
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right

    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'back.jpg'

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'score.jpg'
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        id: score1
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player1.score)

    Label:
        id: score2
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player2.score)

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width - self.width
        center_y: root.center_y

    Button:
        id: btnExit
        text: 'Exit'
        on_press: app.stop()
        pos: 52, 1
        size: 35, 30

    Button:
        id: btnPause
        text: 'Pause'
        on_press:
            root.remove_widget(player_right)
            root.remove_widget(player_left)
            root.remove_widget(score1)
            root.remove_widget(score2)
        pos: 1, 1
        size: 50, 30

    Button:
        id: btnResume
        text: 'Resume'
        on_press:
            root.add_widget(player_right)
            root.add_widget(player_left)
            root.add_widget(score1)
            root.add_widget(score2)
        pos: 88, 1
        size: 58, 30

    Label:
        id: winner
        font_size: 100
        center_x: root.width /2
        top: root.top - 180
        text:
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with an emphasis on "minimal". There is no reason for you to dump your entire project on us.

Comment: Also. make sure it is reproducible. I run your posted code and do not see that error.

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html